# angular + rails 5 (flapper news) - infinite loop error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

recently I have tried to go through a ruby on rails + angular tutorial.

place i got stuck on : https://thinkster.io/tutorials/angular-rails/wiring-everything-up

so far : https://github.com/grfx1985/angular-rails-example

This tutorial is designed to go with rails-4. I have started building it on rails-5.

Up to this state I had no problems so far.

I got stuck on a bizarre problem. Trying to wire up the existing state of the app with the rails back-end. The method to get all the records - one of the first steps to combine the front with the back (last commit) is looping itself trying to receive the data from "posts.json". Eventually it crashes the browser (firefox, chrome - recent versions).

localhost:3000/posts.json dose render the json.

I went through the code comparing it with other people repositories to see if mixed something up, but still was not able to find what is wrong. At this point I am not sure what is the reason for this behavior.

APP.js :

```
angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router', 'templates'])
.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: 'home/_home.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl',

      commented below app works: 
      -------------
      resolve: {
        postPromise: ['posts', function(posts){
          return posts.getAll();
        }]
        }
      -------------
    })
    .state('posts', {
      url: '/posts/{id}',
      templateUrl: 'posts/_posts.html',
      controller: 'PostsCtrl'
    })
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}])
```

posts.js file :

```
angular.module('flapperNews')
.factory('posts', ['$http', function($http){
  var o = {
    posts: []
  };
  ---- this is not working ----
  o.getAll = function() {
        return $http.get('/posts.json').success(function(data){
        angular.copy(data, o.posts);
    });
  };
  -----------------------------

  o.create = function(post) {
    return $http.post('/posts.json', post).success(function(data){
      o.posts.push(data);
    });
  };

  return o;
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the version of angular provided via

`//= require angular` (1.6.2 at this time)

gets You the newest possible

so changing the setup and removing the line, and also including the initial script tag :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
```

inside the `application.html.erb` file fixes the issue

Comment: if You carry on with this answer You will be able to go through the tutorial as it is :) the second answer is better because it lets You use the current angular version. But will probably generate some issues going through the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Found this post because I'm also having the same issues, and managed to find a solution that allows you to continue to use 1.6.x. According to [this page](https://toddmotto.com/angular-1-6-is-here#http-success-and-error), the success() and error() methods have been deprecated, and replaced with then() and catch(). So, I changed the success() call to then() in my code, and it's working correctly for me.

posts.js:

```
angular.module('flapperNews')
    .factory('posts', [
        '$http',
        function($http) {
            var o = {
                posts: []
            };
            o.getAll = function() {
                return $http.get('/posts.json').then(function(data) {
                    angular.copy(data, o.posts)
                })
            };
            return o;
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: thanks for Your answer :) with this we can carry on with the rails way of managing assets.